Get subpart headers of multipart payload from PHP/PSR-7 ServerRequestInterface
When sending an HTTP multipart/form-data payload, it is possible to add additional headers to the individual component parts. For example, a CURL command like this:
curl -v --trace-ascii - -X POST https://dev-server/api/intake -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -F 'data={"json":{"Yep": "this is JSON"}};type=application/json'

Results in an HTTP request like this:
POST /api/intake HTTP/2
Host: dev-server
User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer long-token-here
Content-Length: 213
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------lQNQ3xgpz1neU0tlQTPXnF

--------------------------lQNQ3xgpz1neU0tlQTPXnF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: application/json

{"json":{"Yep": "this is JSON"}}
--------------------------lQNQ3xgpz1neU0tlQTPXnF--

I'm using PHP to implement an API endpoint, and using the PSR-7 ServerRequestInterface to capture the request data. The trouble is, while I can easily get ahold of the data JSON string using $message->getParsedBody(), I don't see a way to get ahold of that associated Content-Type: application/json header.
Even trying to parse the body myself instead of letting PHP do it is not viable.
// This returns an empty string, presumably because `php://input`
// is not available for "multipart/form-data" requests
$message->getBody()->getContents();
// (I can't globally disable the `enable_post_data_reading` php.ini setting, 
// because other parts of the application rely on it, and doing it via `ini_set` 
// seems to have no effect.)

Is there a supported way to obtain these subpart headers?
(I'm aware I can just make the entire request an application/json request. That isn't my goal; I want to use a multipart request.)
